# My repeated HTML Bootstrap collapse function only works for the first set

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm creating a page that is a directory where each issue has a set of articles and authors. I'm implementing a function that cuts a list of articles after its fourth element and collapses the remaining with a 'See more' button. On the website, it properly cuts the lists and shows the button, but this button only works properly the first time it shows up. If you try clicking all of the other 'See more' buttons, it only expands the very first list and not the one it's supposed to expand.

I imagine it has to do with IDs and class, but I haven't figured out any solutions thus far.

```html
     <div class="article-list">
         {% for article in issue.articles|slice:":4" %}
          <div class="section-article">
            <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="name">{{article.title}}</p></a>

            {% for author in article.contributors.all %}
              <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
         {% endfor %}

         <!-- if there are more than 5 articles in an issue -->
         {% if issue.articles|slice:"5:" %}

            <!-- create a collapse div -->
             <div id="collapsearticle_{{ issue.id }}" class="collapse">
               {% for article in issue.articles|slice:"5:" %}
                 <div class="section-article">
                   <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="name">{{article.title}}</p></a>
                   {% for author in article.contributors.all %}
                     <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a>
                   {% endfor %}
                 </div>
               {% endfor %}
             </div>

             <div class="text-center">
               <div class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsearticle_{{ issue.id }}"> View more &#8964; </div>
             </div>

         {% endif %}

       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works base on the example below. May be you can check the issue_id on the browser

```
<div id="collapsearticle_1" class="collapse">
  <div class="section-article">
    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="name">{{article.title}}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <div class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsearticle_1"> View more &#8964; </div>
</div>

<div id="collapsearticle_2" class="collapse">
  <div class="section-article">
    <a href="{{ article.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="name">{{article.title}}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
    <a href="{{ author.get_absolute_url }}"><p class="no-decoration author">{{ author.name }}</p></a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
  <div class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsearticle_2"> View more &#8964; </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can’t actually do this since the webpage isn’t static and draws from another file to fill the page up with it’s issues (and the articles inside of them). So I can’t actually physically make certain issue lists collapsible, but instead have to make a function that will recognize when a list is too long and collapse accordingly

Comment: you open the website and check the inspect element of the div id, is it display accordingly. i guess you are using template engine (twig?).
from my code, the collapse work correctly, meaning that the output of the template has some issues with the
    <div id="collapsearticle_{{ issue.id }}" class="collapse">
===> {{ issue.id }}
check the output of {{ issue.id }}, see is it correct